# how to install phpshield loaders on centos 5 64 bit, (i have php 5.3.8)

Tags: php, centos, centos5, php5, video

I have followed [this tutorial](http://wiki.phpmotion.com/PHPShield53) and [this one](http://phpmotionwiz.com/how-to-install-phpshield-loaders), I have downloaded [the proper version](http://phpshield.com/loaders/) and still cannot get [phpmotion](http://www.phpmotion.com/) to detect it. Before i contact the support team for help, I just want to know if there's a third way to install phpshield loaders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download loaders for Linux 64b and copy ixed.5.3.lin inside /usr/lib64/php/modules dir.

Then open /etc/php.ini and add the next line at the end of the file

> extension=ixed.5.3.lin

Save the changes and restart apache (service httpd restart)